# Spam on /wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/109250/feedback

Tags: contact-form-7

I started seeing an increased amount of spam messages that are following the same pattern and entering the site from wp-JSON/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/109250/feedback

Is anyone else experiencing this on WP using Contact Form 7?

Any tips on how to block this page for external viewing?

I tried reCAPTCHA v3, but the amount of false positives that regular users are getting is significant.